# Default view in ui-router w/ overwrite option

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following state in my app:

```
state('app', {
                url: '',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/layouts/app.html',
                controller: 'appController'
            });
```

The app.html layout have those views:

```
<header id="topbar" ui-view="top"></header>
<section id="content" ui-view="content"></section>
```

The "top" view is basically the breadcrumb. But in some features, they are more complex and have a lot of buttons, tabs, etc.

So, in my states, I have:

```
.state("dashboard", {
            parent: 'app',
            url: '/dashboard',
            views: {
                'top': { templateUrl: "app/dashboard/top.html" }
                'content': { templateUrl: "app/dashboard/dashboard.html" }
            },
            controller: 'Dashboard as vm',
            data: { requireAuth: true }
        });
```

Is there any way to have a default top template in all states, and only if I want, overwrite this template?

I already tried put the default template into the view:

```
<header id="topbar" ui-view="top">
   <ul class="breadcrumb">[...]</ul>
</header>
```

Works, but give me a lag between state changes (the default top disapears after the custom top has loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1:

#### Define the layout in the index (or a parent state) and target the named views at the root state

[Plunk 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/H6dTU56MCjz9IO5vPehi?p=preview)

index.html:

```
  <body ng-app="plunker">
        <a ui-sref='app.child1'>Go to child1</a>
        <a ui-sref='app.child2'>Go to child</a>
        <h1>Hi from unnamed view in app state</h1>
        <div ui-view='header'></div>
        <div ui-view='content'></div>
  </body>
```

config:

```
  $stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: "",
    views: {
      "header@": {
        template: "<h3>Default header template</h3>"
      },
      "content@": {
        template: "<h5>Default content template</h3>"
      }
    }
  }).state('app.child1', {
    url: '/child1',
    views: {
      "header@": {
        template: "<small>Header for child1</small>"
      },
      "content@": {
        template: "<a ui-sref='^'>Back to parent</a><h1>child1</h1>"
      }
    }
  }).state('app.child2', {
    url: '/child2',
    views: {
      "header@": {
        template: "<small>Header for child2</small>"
      },
      "content@": {
        template: "<a ui-sref='^'>Back to parent</a><h1>child1</h1>"
      }
    }
  });
```

## Option 2

#### Define the layout in the app state, as well as the default views to plug into the layout

[Plunk 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/rRUVAUz9INOizGK0gnnm?p=preview)

index.html:

```
  <body ng-app="plunker">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </body>
```

config:

```
 $stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: "",
    views: {
      "header@app": {
        template: "<h3>Default header template</h3>"
      },
      "content@app": {
        template: "<h5>Default content template</h3>"
      },
      "@": {
        template: "<a ui-sref='.child1'>Go to child1</a>" + 
        "<a ui-sref='.child2'>Go to child2</a>" +
        "<h1>Hi from unnamed view in app state</h1>" +
        "<div ui-view='header'></div>" + 
        "<div ui-view='content'></div>"
      }
    }
  }).state('app.child1', {
    url: '/child1',
    views: {
      "header@app": {
        template: "<small>Header for child1</small>"
      },
      "content@app": {
        template: "<a ui-sref='^'>Back to parent</a><h1>child1</h1>"
      }
    }
  }).state('app.child2', {
    url: '/child2',
    views: {
      "header@app": {
        template: "<small>Header for child2</small>"
      },
      "content@app": {
        template: "<a ui-sref='^'>Back to parent</a><h1>child2</h1>"
      }
    }
  });
```